# Overriding existing CSS files

Tags: css, themes, myfaces

I want to use a css file for applying a theme. I am using myfaces that has one custom component named Scheduler.
Scheduler component is using its own css file that is within jarfile(tomahawk12-1.1.10.jar)
named schedule.css and has three theme(default , outlook, and evelutionary) but I want to use my own css file for applying theme in my project.
How can I overwrite that css file?

Comment: If you create your own css file with the same css classes and include after those other files, your rules will overwrite the previous ones.

Answer (score 3):

Well it depends on if you want to completely overwrite the CSS files by changing their contents (just save over the files and possibly keep a backup copy), or if you want to just use the `!important` feature with your own custom stylesheet in CSS, exampled below:

```
leftSide {  
    background-color: #0f0 !important;  
}
```

When the `!important` declaration is used on a specific property/value pair, it will cause that particular value to escape the cascade and become, as the name suggests, the most important value for that property, *overriding* any others.
Here is more information on CSS's `!important` feature: http://www.impressivewebs.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-important-css-declaration/

Comment: In most cases one don't need the `!important`-rule to overwrite CSS statements. Just repeat the selector and add it after the original (file). »[`!important` can be highly abused and make for messy and hard to maintain CSS](http://css-tricks.com/9462-when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)«